# How do I lower Chrome's memory usage?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, speed

Chrome is fast and all, but seriously?

[image: TaskManager Screenshot]

I only have **3 regular tabs open** and the settings tab. I'd trade a little speed for some RAM. How can I make Chrome use less memory?

**Update**

The about memory page:

[image]

Comment: Well, that does look like something's going wrong. What does `about:memory` say?

Comment: @Dennis take a look, looks like my extensions might be some of the problem too.

Comment: That explains the processes then. 850 MiB memory usage for 6 tabs and 10 extensions is also not that high. If you need the RAM for something else, just restart Chrome. That will release part of the memory.

Comment: Yea, I used to get something similar when I had like 15+ extensions enabled. You should see a clear difference if you start Chrome in Incognito mode (if you haven't enabled the extensions for Incognito manually). As @Dennis mentioned, restarting will temporarily fix that, disabling some of the extensions is a better option if you don't really need all of them.

Comment: @sabrefresco I did just that, made a little difference, it's amazing how the extensions pile up after a while. kinda like the startup items in Windows, every so often you gotta go in and clean them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest disabling any extensions that you don't require frequently. The memory used by extensions can really pile up if you never go through and disable the ones you don't need all the time.

Comment: That's not ideal. Why can't Chrome manage their extensions? What's the point of having extensions if they cause memory issues? I have 2-3 extensions on and I'm getting severe memory issues to the point of force quit. Any way to solve this?

Comment: You could also try using an ad blocker. Lots of tracking and ad scripts will significantly increase memory usage.